# Can we host two angular projects under same port

Tags: angular, iis, hosting, iis-10

I have two angular projects developed in `angular2`. One is public portal and other is admin. If I am hosting the main portal as http://myaddress.com then I need to host the admin under it; ie. the url should be http://myaddress.com/admin. This has to be tested in `IIS`.

Comment: Have you heard about the term feature module and authGuard ?

Comment: No, I am new to angular. Is there a solution for the requirement?

Comment: @TechDo may be i'm wrong.but can't you just host main in root  and admin project in admin directory ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have to host both project on their respective directory (IIS configuration needed) and build/deploy your apps with the `base-href` option :

```
ng build --prod --base-href=/admin // admin app
ng build --prod // public app
```

Comment: Yes @Cetia, it worked for me. I manually changed the `<base href="/admin/">` in index.html.

Comment: you should not. ng serve will serve it on / when in dev mode, but will generate a build working on /admin with the option I given you.

Answer (score 1):

My answer would be mostly theoretical for this.

1. Create a npm bundle of `admin` project (something like ng-packagr would help). There is a format to expose all the modules which you want to access outside of this project. You can find details on google about this. something like `index.ts` etc
2. Include it in `package.json` of Main Project as `dependency`.
3. Try to create a routing inside `MainProject` and use lazy loading in routing for better performance.  Something like:

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: 'IAmINMainProjec',
        canActivate: [TrafficGuard],
        pathMatch: 'full'
       // and what not..
    },
    {
        path: 'admin',
         loadChildren:
                    './modules/widget-wrappers/#AdminWrapperModule',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
```

**AdminWrapperModule**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        AdminModule,
    ]
})
export class AdminWrapperModule{}
```

*the above code is just for reference purpose :D*

#### Update

In my project, we have several modules (4 to be precise) similar to `admin` in your case, and we realized that it was very time consuming to have 4 projects getting build (with each project having build time of approx 7 mins). So we ended up implementing [nrwl](https://github.com/nrwl). This tool helped us to pull all 4 projects under our main project. This helped to reduce time as we no longer had to build 2 projects (one `Admin` and another `MainProject`) before actually deploying the code. Take a look at it if you really need that. If you need more segregation of projects then don't go for `Nrwl`.

Comment: Thanks @Shashank Vivek, let me try this.

Comment: @TechDo Check my update as well. I have used it in my project but check if you really need to get into that direction. Its all project specific decisions

Comment: Hi @Vivek, the "correct answer" marked method worked for me (plz refer it). So, to be frank, I didn't spend much time on your method.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me with just one running locally and other one in local network [Image of running both simultaneously](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvkkQ.png)

The one which you are running in local network using the following command :

> ng serve --host 0.0.0.0

can be accessed using local ip address eg :

> http://192.168.0.152:4200

Which can be accessed using following command in terminal
windows :

> ipconfig

on linux/mac:

> ifconfig

and the other one which you are running using

> ng serve

can be accessed using
http://localhost:4200

Comment: How would you call this in the browser?

Comment: @Gogowitsch I have updated answer to be more clear , if you still have any doubts , please let me know.