# How to run two angular apps on the same port

Tags: angular, port

I am trying to run two angular apps on the same port, for developping i am using `http://localhost:4200`. Does anyone knows how to run two angular apps on the same port? Is there any easy solution for it? If anyone knows how to do that, could you tell me how to add that to my app. Thank you!

This is my **angular json**, it could help to solve this problem:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app1": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "projects/app1",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/app1/src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/app1",
            "index": "projects/app1/src/index.html",
            "main": "projects/app1/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/app1/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/app1/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "projects/app1/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/app1/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/app1/src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "projects/app1/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "projects/app1/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app1:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "app1:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app1:build"
          }
        },
      }
    },

    "app2": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "projects/app2",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/app2/src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/app2",
            "index": "projects/app2/src/index.html",
            "main": "projects/app2/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/app2/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/app2/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "projects/app2/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/app2/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/app2/src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "projects/app2/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "projects/app2/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app2:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "app2:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app2:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/app2/src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/app2/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/app2/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/app2/karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "projects/app2/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/app2/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/app2/src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "app1"
}
```

Comment: Use apache httpd as proxy for example

Comment: You only have to host both project on their respective directory (IIS configuration needed) and build/deploy your apps with the base-href option

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your ultimate objective, this post should answer your question. You will need to build and host both applications. One will need to use a different base-href option. [Can we host two angular projects under same port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56660063/can-we-host-two-angular-projects-under-same-port)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33661346)